# Mean and variance of the area of the circle

Tags: probability, uniform-distribution

> If a random circle has a radius that is uniformly distributed on the interval $(0,2)$, what are the mean and variance of the area of the circle?

we have $A=\pi r^2$ and $r$ is uniformly distributed on $(0,2)$, thus, $F(A)=1$ on $(0,2)$ with $A$ is defined on $[0,\pi]$. SO,

$$F(A)=Pr(A<a)=Pr(\pi r^2<a)=Pr(-\sqrt{\frac{a}{\pi}}<r<\sqrt{\frac{a}{\pi}})$$
$$F(A)=\int_{0}^{\sqrt{\frac{a}{\pi}}}1\,dx=\sqrt{\frac{a}{\pi}}\qquad\text{then I will have} \;\;\;f(a)=\frac{1}{2a\pi}$$
When I calculate the mean, I didn't get $4\pi/3$. Where I did wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $r$ is uniformly distributed on $[0,2]$ then the density function for $r$ is $1/2$. Thus the expected value if the area is
$$
\int_0^2 \pi r^2\, 1/2\, dr =4\pi/3
$$
and the variance is 
$$
\int_0^2 (\pi r^2- 4\pi/3)^2\, 1/2\, dr = 64\pi^2/45.
$$

Where did you go wrong? Usually the notation $F$ stands for the cumulative distribution function, you probably meant the density function which is $f(r)=1/2$. If you wanted the CDF for the area, then 
$$
F(a)=P(\pi r^2\leq a)=P(0\leq r\leq \sqrt{a/\pi})=1/2 \sqrt{a/\pi}
$$
(for $0\leq r\leq 2$, i.e. $0\leq a \leq \pi\, 2^2=4\pi$). You can then get the mean as
$$
\int_0^{4\pi}a \, F'(a)\, da = \int_0^{4\pi}\, \frac{1}{\sqrt{16\, a\, \pi}}\, da=4\pi/3.
$$

Answer (score 0):

$$Mean(A)=\frac{\int_{0}^{2}\pi r^2}{2-0}\,dr= 4\pi/3$$